# Проблема с оформлением сайта

Tags: html5

Впервые делаю что-то наподобие сайта и столкнулся с такой проблемой, как непонятные **отступы по краям** блока(см.скрин). Попробовал уже все что только можно, но пофиксить не могу. Хелп.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5,html,css">
        <meta name="description" contents="html5tempvals">
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
        <!---<script src="javascriptfile.js"></script>--->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> </link>
        <!---<lin rel="icon" href="myicon.ico"/>--->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cookie&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        
        <title>Title of page</title>
    </head> 
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Main</a>
            <a href="about us.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact us.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>WELCOME TO MY SITE</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

### (код из HTML)

```
header  
{   
    font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;  
    font-size: 30px;  
    text-align: center;  
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    /*background:url("shapka1.jpg") center no-repeat;*/  
    background-color: yellow;  
    margin: 0px;  
    width: 100%;  
}
```

(код из CSS)

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Приведите [mcve] в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Это отступы страницы, которые называются `margin`. По стандарту они есть у каждой страницы, но вы можете их убрать. Создайте файл НАЗВАНИЕ.css, подключите его в header'e html файла с помощью `<link rel="stylesheet" href="НАЗВАНИЕ.css">` и в css **исправьте отступы** для страницы:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Если это не помогает и у вас картинка внутри какого-либо блока Х, то нужно смотреть стили для этого блока в devtools. Чтобы его открыть нажмите F12 и там смотрите стили для блока Х или любого другого элемента, в котором находится ваша картинка\блок.

А вообще - не **выкладывайте вопрос без хотя бы приблизительного кода**, который вы имеете, поскольку это может быть не margin, а что угодно

Comment: @Дмитрий добавьте это в ответ, и html код тоже, думаете это удобно читать такое в комментарии в одну строку?

Comment: дополнил в вопросе код

Comment: Как я и писал, вам нужно добавить в стили то что я привел в ответе с `body`. тогда отступ уйдет. Если этот ответ вам помог - вы можете его принять.